# AWS S3 PHP SDK, S3Client class not found

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, class, sdk, namespaces

I am trying to set up a connection to an Amazon S3 storage using their PHP SDK v3.

I am following this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/getting-started_basic-usage.html

So I installed the SDK using Composer and created a file called ftptest.php (don't mind the name), that contains this:

```
<?PHP
require '/home/printzel/public_html/new/vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

//Create a S3Client
$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'nl-ams1'
]);
?>
```

But when going to the page, I get a HTTP 500 error. When checking my error log, I see this:

```
[01-Apr-2021 14:01:27 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Aws\S3\S3Client' not found in /home/printzel/public_html/new/ftptest.php:9
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/printzel/public_html/new/ftptest.php on line 9
```

I included my autoload file as you can see. But for some reason it can't find the correct class, why?

This is currently how my structure looks like on my server:

Autoload location:

```
/home/printzel/public_html/new/vendor/autoload.php
```

AWS folder location:

```
/home/printzel/public_html/new/vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src
```

composer.json in my root:

```
{
    "require": {
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.176"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your autoloader generated by composer? Can you post the content of composer.json here?

Comment: @AleksandarJakovljevic Yes. I added my composer.json contents above.

Comment: This is indeed strange. You did check that vendor files are actually in place? :)
What is your PHP version?

Comment: @AleksandarJakovljevic Yes all files are in place, if I look for S3Client.php it is exactly in the path I expect it to be. I am using PHP 7.3

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, sorry man ... I even tried this out and "it works on my machine".

Comment: actually got the idea just this moment. Could you check the permissions and ownership of the vendor directory and subdirectories? It is a possibility that composer was run under a different user compared to the user that your php script is being run and then files exist but are actually inaccessible by that particular user.

Comment: I'd also start poking around at the files inside of `vendor/composer`, specifically `autoload_psr4.php`, to see if the namespace is in there. I'd then put some debug code into `vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php` in the `loadClass` or `findFile` methods

Answer (score 1):

You need replace `Aws\S3\S3Client` with `S3Client`:

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

//Create a S3Client
$s3 = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'nl-ams1'
]);
```

More detail is here - [Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php)

Hope help you

Also you can to create the alias:

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client as AwsClient;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

//Create a S3Client
$s3 = new AwsClient([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'nl-ams1'
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I still get the same error with both parts, with or without alias. I get: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Aws\S3\S3Client' not found in /home/printzel/public_html/new/ftptest.php:8`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include the path to the SDK autoloader, I suggest you use the relative path like below.

```
// require the amazon sdk from your composer vendor dir
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Once you have done, if its still fails you must have issue on the sdk path or sdk version, that, make sure you follow below steps one by one and redo them one by one.

**1. Add AWS SDK for PHP as a dependency via Composer**

If Composer is already installed globally on your system, run the following in the base directory of your project to install AWS SDK for PHP as a dependency:

```
composer require aws/aws-sdk-php
```

**2. Add autoloader to your php scripts**

To utilize the AWS SDK for PHP in your scripts, include the autoloader in your scripts, as follows.

```
<?php
   require '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';
?>
```

**3. Make sure you have the access right keys setup in the enr.**

You need AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY. set in the enr.  if you do you can ignore the passing of the AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID to the code.

```
<?php

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

define('AWS_KEY', 'place access key here');
define('AWS_SECRET_KEY', 'place secret key here');

// require the amazon sdk from your composer vendor dir
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiate the S3 class and point it at the desired host
$client = new S3Client([
    'region' => '',
    'version' => '2021-03-01',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID ,
        'secret' => AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
    ]
]);
```